# Apache & OS X FileVault 2

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

Over the weekend I enabled FileVault 2 on OS 10.8.4.

When I fired up MAMP PRO just now, I receive the following error:

> Apache wasn't able to start. Please check log for more information.

When I look at my log, the last line is:

> Fri Jun 21 18:57:52 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

I have tried stopping and restarting Apache.

If I run: `sudo apachectl start`, and then try to start MAMP, I receive a different error message:

```
The built in Apache is active which can cause a port conflict with at least one of your virtual hosts.

It's recommended either to choose a port different than 80 or to stop the built in Apache.
```

Enabling FileVault is the only thing I can think of since Friday that could have potentially affected Apache. But I'm not sure how to debug what exactly the problem is?

Comment: `sudo apachectl start` is starting the system Apache, which will conflict with the version MAMP includes; do `sudo apachectl stop`, then try restarting MAMP and see if the problem remains.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, yea I tried that as well. No joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled FileVault, did a system reboot, and everything is back to normal. So apparently there are some issues with running Mac Apache and FileVault. Not much has been said about it online. Hopefully this thread can serve some purpose and we can figure out a solution.